# How to prove that $x^\top M y = y^\top M x$ if $M$ is a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

I am not sure what the correct way to prove

$$x^\top M y = y^\top M x$$

is if $M$ is symmetric matrix of $k$ rows and $x$ and $y$ are vectors of length $k$. Could you give me some hint in the right direction?

Comment: Your first hint is to find the dimension of the matrix $x^TMy$, and therefore see that it is symmetric. Once you take it's transpose, you get the other side of the equation i.e. $y^T Mx$.

Comment: The thing is, that result of that multiplication is a scalar and I am not sure how is defined transposition of scalar.

Comment: A scalar is a $1 \times 1$ matrix! It's transpose is itself, and hence you can directly take the transpose, and get the answer. Otherwise, you will have to use  dummy indices,like the below answer.

Comment: If you know $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$ and $(A^t)^t=A$ you are done.

Comment: Are you sure that you can look at scalar as 1x1 matrix? Wouldn't there be some inconsistencies like that you can't multiply it with other matrices which dont have dim 1?

Comment: @NormanOne: It's the other way around in this case. The result of your matrix multiplication is really a $1\times 1$ matrix (since you always get a matrix when you multiply matrices). It's just that $1 \times 1$ matrices are usually written as scalars for simplicity.

Comment: Of course, now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use Einstein notation without $\sum$.

$($ A repeated index means sum.$)$

$$x^t*M*y=x_i(M*y)_i$$

$$=x_i.M_{ij}.y_j$$

$$=x_i.M_{ji}.y_j$$

since $M$ is symetric.

$$=y_j.M_{ji}.x_i$$

$$=y_j.(M*x)_j$$

$$=y^t*M*x$$

$i$ and $j$ are dummy indices.